# How to upload Metapackage Extensions in Magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2marketplace

How to Upload Metapackage extension in Magento Marketplace?
I have two dependent extensions. Can I upload the dependent extension as individual extension?

How to create shared package while uploading the Metapackage extension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do into the following ways.

1. Submit 2 dependent extension as Shared Package and First approve that one. For Submit the Shared package you find the options on top menu, see this one : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJ07.png
2. Now you need to submit Main Extension where select those 2 extension as Shared Package. You can found option here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyQc6.png

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: If answer help you please upvote and accept as solution. so it will help other in community.